# Trace of product of six Pauli matrices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace

Using the standard definition of the Pauli matrices with the zeroth included, i.e.

$$ \sigma^{\mu} = (I, \sigma^i) $$
$$  \bar \sigma^{\mu} = (I, -\sigma^i) $$

it's a standard result that
$$ Tr[\sigma^{\mu} \bar \sigma^{\nu}] = 2\eta^{\mu \nu} $$
which is easy enough to verify. Several sources e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08246 also give an analagous result for the trace of the product of four,
$$ Tr[\sigma^{\mu_1} \bar \sigma^{\mu_2} \sigma^{\mu_3} \bar \sigma^{\mu_4}] = 2\eta^{\mu_1 \mu_2}\eta^{\mu_3 \mu_4} + 2\eta^{\mu_1 \mu_4}\eta^{\mu_2 \mu_3} - 2\eta^{\mu_1 \mu_3}\eta^{\mu_2 \mu_4} - 2i \varepsilon^{\mu_1\mu_2\mu_3\mu_4}. $$

None of the standard references go as far as six, but I'd like to know whether there is a similarly compact result for the product of six sigma matrices, i.e.
$$Tr[\sigma^{\mu_1} \bar \sigma^{\mu_2} \sigma^{\mu_3} \bar \sigma^{\mu_4} \sigma^{\mu_5} \bar \sigma^{\mu_6}]?$$

Comment: Might just want to follow the proof for 4 and see if you can use the same methods

Comment: @doublefelix None of the references allude to the method of proof used for 4; it's easy enough to verify it but I've not seen a derivation. Certainly such a reference would likely resolve the issue for six!

Comment: I think you may have a typo on the far RHS of your equation for the trace of four pauli matrices. (In the indices of the totally antisymmetric tensor.)

Comment: @R.W Hmm then sorry for my uninformed suggestion. I don't have much else to offer but best of luck to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalize the result for the [product of two Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product) to include the identity matrix. You can verify the factors that I just jotted down:
$$\sigma^\mu\sigma^\nu=(\delta^{\mu\nu}-2\delta^{\mu0}\delta^{\nu0})I+(1-\delta^{\mu0})(1-\delta^{\nu0})\epsilon^{\mu\nu}_{\eta}\sigma^\eta+\delta^{\mu0}\sigma^\nu+\delta^{\nu0}\sigma^\mu.$$ Now iterate this process for the product of more matrices, find which terms are proportional to $I$, and those will be the only ones contributing to the trace (with an extra factor of 2 from $\mathrm{Tr}(I)$. You will need to use concatenation properties of [Levi-Civita tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Product_2) and the like.

There might be some nice induction you can do, but there will regardless be an increasing number of terms, which is probably why most people don't write these expressions down in general.

If you want to use this for the components of $\bar{\sigma}$ you'll need to add minus signs as appropriate. One can do this by writing, without any summation convention, $\bar{\sigma}^\mu=(\delta^{\mu0}-1)\sigma^\mu+\delta^{\mu0}\sigma^\mu$. One can also do this by not caring about upper and lower indices, using Einstein sum conventions, and writing $\bar{\sigma}^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\sigma^\mu$.

Comment: In the question, there are also barred $\bar\sigma^\mu$ matrices. I don't see how this answer takes those into account. Shouldn’t you give a formula for $\sigma^\mu\bar\sigma^\nu$?

Comment: @Ghoster this formula works for the actual components, which are just the Pauli matrices and the identity matrix, so any product will just be products of those (there are no Einstein sum rules or anything to be worried about). You can add minus signs as you please

Comment: @Ghoster I preferred to work with the bars and Einstein summation in the end. There are well known rules for the product and trace of four involving bars, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08246.pdf. Taking the result for the product of four, multiplying it by another two, and then taking trace and using the trace formula for four Paulis indeed yields a fairly neat result. In particular for the application I had in mind, keeping 4D Levi-Civitas in the mix is strongly preferable.